# what is `::content` in a css?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

I wonder what is `::content` in a css rule ?

The thing is that when I use AdBlock Plus(**for chrome**), it seems that it will add a css rule to my websites, as below:

[image]

It will make the dom hidden (`display: none`), and I try to reset the css to make it seen using `setTimeout`, but I failed, both csses (the ABP adds and I add) work, so the dom is still not seen.

I check the css the ABP adds, finding **::content**, I wonder it's the reason why I cannot reset the css rules, but after google, I find nothing useful.

So I come here to see if there is someone to help me! With great thanks!

Comment: `::content` seems like non standard/secret pseudo-element. What node in normal or shadow tree it represents is unknown, we only can guess unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having trouble finding official documentation on this pseudo-element selector, but it's a selector for Shadow DOM elements. See the following excerpts from the AdBlock Plus Chrome extensions source code:

#### [`include.preload.js` `convertSelectorsForShadowDOM`](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluschrome/blob/96edb846c82aead083af8bfafb1212cef595e101/include.preload.js#L242-L245)

```
function convertSelectorsForShadowDOM(selectors)
{
  var result = [];
  var prefix = "::content ";
```

...

#### [`include.preload.js` call to `convertSelectorsForShadowDOM`](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluschrome/blob/96edb846c82aead083af8bfafb1212cef595e101/include.preload.js#L328-L332)

```
    // If using shadow DOM, we have to add the ::content pseudo-element
    // before each selector, in order to match elements within the
    // insertion point.
    if (shadow)
      selectors = convertSelectorsForShadowDOM(selectors);
```

Comment: Searching for "content pseudo-element" (with quotes) turns up shadow-dom and css-scoping.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, we both just found the same duplicate.

Comment: thanks a lot ! Although it seems to be a lot of trouble ahead !